# trying to create a function in c that takes in user input and returns a string of char

Tags: c

No matter what I try I get an error. I'll remove the pointer, remove the malloc, I've tried reading in the user input in dfferent ways. I come form a java background and very confused on why none of this is working. Also I am not trying to return an array of strings i am just trying to return a string or a single array of chars in c

```
 main(){
        char *c = getResources();
 }

 char * getResources(){
       char *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
       fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);      /* read in a line */
       return *str;
 }
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I think you just need to `return str;`.

Comment: Change `return *str` into `return str`. Your form returns a `char` and _not_ a pointer to to a `char` array. Recompile with `-Wall` to help.

Comment: main.c:19:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getResources' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Comment: `sizeof(str)` is going to get you the size of a pointer (usually 4 on a 32-bit machine, 8 on a 64-bit machine), not the size of your buffer. This is pretty much always going to be larger than the size of your buffer, which is only 3 bytes. This is going to cause an overflow, which will crash if you're lucky, or do much worse things if you're not.

Comment: ^
main.c:30:10: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'char' with an expression of type 'char *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]

main.c:31:11: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'char *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]

Comment: You'll need to add a function prototype before main: `char* getResources(void);`

Comment: You don't have a function prototype. THat's what the compiler warning means.

Comment: Honestly, I'd suggest getting a good book on the C language, or taking a class. Coding in C without having a solid understanding of the fundamentals can cause pretty catastrophic failures.

Comment: Your length is `3` [very short]. Try doing the malloc with (e.g. `80` instead of `3`) and do: `fgets(str,80,stdin)` because your current `fgets` length claims _more_ space than you actually allocated. Better yet (e.g.): `#define LEN 80` and replace the hard coded values with `LEN`

Comment: @CraigEstey The `#define` method is the correct way to go about this.

Comment: @Ethan please add your comment about *warning: incompatible pointer* into the question.

Answer (score 3):

There are many errors in your code.

The first one is the return value of the *getResources()* function. You are returning the value pointed by (**str*), which is a single char, but you want to return the whole array.
To fix it you should write *return str*.

The second one is in the *sizeof()* operator, which is a compile-time operator. Since it is executed on compile time, it doesn't now the size of the char array malloc-ed at runtime, but only the size of the pointer itself.
Therefore you can't use it this way, but you have to replace it with the actual size of the array.

The third one is in the functions order. You can't use a function that wasn't previously declared. You can either move the full function above the main() or you can just declare it above the main() and leave the implementation behind it.

Finally, the main() function should return an integer.

Bonus tip: don't forget to free the malloc-ed pointer when you don't need it anymore

The fixed code may be as follow:

```
 char * getResources(){
   size_t str_size = 3;
   char *str = malloc(str_size);
   fgets(str, str_size, stdin);      /* read in a line */
   return str;
 }

 int main(){
    char *c = getResources();
    /* do something with c */
    free(c);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Never cast the return value from `malloc`. It's not necessary and it hides coding errors.

Comment: It will be better if the type of `str_size` is `size_t`.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition, and a buffer size of `3` for user input is useless.

Comment: I changed the code according to your suggestions. @WeatherVane The length of the user input depends on what kind of input is expected. For example, it may need just the country code to get the correct resources, therefore 3 is the right length for "it\0", "en\n", "fr\0" and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that you are returning `*str` instead of the pointer `str`:

```
return str;
```

Also, you are reading `sizeof(str)` characters, which is the size of a pointer, that can vary across platforms.
So instead, you need to change that to `3`, the number of characters allocated for `str`:

```
fgets(str, 3, stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is probably among the worst pieces of C code out there, but it compiles without a warning. Please definitely make sure to read all comments made on your answer, and the info given in the answer by medalib and Andrea.
My code merely condenses all that into a chunk of stuff you can copy paste...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// define it before you use it; a prototype would also have worked
char* getResources(){
       char *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
       // second param is size of input to be expected;
       // you passed it the size of a pointer, which is most 
       // definitely not what you want
       fgets(str, 3, stdin);      /* read in a line */
       // return the pointer; str is already declared as a pointer,
       // a further * will only de-reference that again
       return str;
 }

int main(){
    char *c = getResources();
    printf("%s\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```